# How to position tabs on a tabcontrol vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

VB.Net, TabStrip control,

Tabs are Align Left or Right and Top or Bottom

I need to start tabs from my own position On Top of the Tab control

Like Internet Explorer, Tabs are starting after HTTP address box, but it will cover full page and Align on the left=0.

Comment: Hmya, Internet Explorer does *not* use a TabControl, its tabs are completely custom drawn.  You can emulate something similar by not using tab pages, just make the TabControl only tall enough to display the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

**To display right-aligned tabs**

1. Add a *TabControl* to your form.
2. Set the *Alignment* property to *Right*.
3. Set the *SizeMode* property to *Fixed*, so that all tabs are the same width.
4. Set the *ItemSize* property to the preferred fixed size for the tabs. Keep in mind that the *ItemSize* property behaves as though the tabs were on top, although they are right-aligned. As a result, in order to make the tabs wider, you must change the *Height* property, and in order to make them taller, you must change the *Width* property.

   In the code example below, *Width* is set to 25 and *Height* is set to 150.
5. Set the *DrawMode* property to *OwnerDrawFixed*.
6. Define a *handler* for the DrawItem event of *TabControl* that renders the text from left to right.

   C#

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       // Remove this call if you do not program using Visual Studio.
       InitializeComponent();

       tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);
   }

   private void tabControl1_DrawItem(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
   {
       Graphics g = e.Graphics;
       Brush _textBrush;

       // Get the item from the collection.
       TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

       // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
       Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

       if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
       {
           // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.

           _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
           g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
       }
       else
       {
           _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
           e.DrawBackground();
       }

       // Use our own font.
       Font _tabFont = new Font("Arial", (float)10.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

       // Draw string. Center the text.
       StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
       _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
       _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
       g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
   ```